# SQL join table to self to find difference

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider the below table

```
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lang` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `channel` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`lang`,`channel`)
)

insert into `temp` (`id`, `lang`, `channel`, `name`) values('1','fr','ds','Jacket');
insert into `temp` (`id`, `lang`, `channel`, `name`) values('1','en','ds','Jacket');
insert into `temp` (`id`, `lang`, `channel`, `name`) values('2','en','ds','Jeans');
insert into `temp` (`id`, `lang`, `channel`, `name`) values('3','en','ds','Sweater');
insert into `temp` (`id`, `lang`, `channel`, `name`) values('1','de','ds','Jacket');
```

The question is how can I find which entries with lang en do not exist for fr?
My head is stuck and I believe this to be a trivial query but I am having one of these days.

Comment: How do you match them? by ID or by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this.  One way is to use a sub-select with `not exists` clause:

```
select id, channel
from temp t1
where t1.lang = 'en'
and not exists (
  select 1
  from temp t2
  where t2.lang = 'fr'
  and t1.id = t2.id
)
```

Alternatively, you can use an outer join:

```
select t1.id, t1.channel
from temp t1
left outer join temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.lang = 'en'
and t2.id is null
```

Comment: Thank you all guys for your answers. All of them work. Accepting Aleks's because of the 2 solutions offered. Thanks again. Long day today.... Easy query

Answer (score 1):

based on @AleksG

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.channel, t1.name
FROM temp t1
LEFT JOIN temp t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.lang = 'fr'
WHERE t1.lang = 'en' AND t2.lang IS NULL
```

Comment: This will produce 0 rows, because in your join you only take rows with `t2.lang = 'fr'` but then also require that `t2.lang is null` - that is it must be both `fr` and `null`

Comment: @AleksG no, the question is for those that don't have a `fr` row, since I'm using `left join` which will keep all the rows of `t1` and then filter out those that actually match `t2.lang = 'fr'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select t.channel, t.name
from temp t
group by t.channel, t.name
having sum(case when t.lang = 'fr' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when t.lang = 'en' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The first condition in the `having` clause counts up the number of times that French appears.  The second counts up the number of times that English appears.  When there are none for French and at least one for English, then the channel and name are in the result set.